# How to set "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" in Firebase hosting

Tags: reactjs, firebase, express

I've set up a Node Express application in Firebase Functions, and a React app in Firebase Hosting (similar to the [template](https://github.com/cjmyles/firebase-react-express) I built, with the exception that I've configured session cookies in express and I'm using Passport JS).

My `firebase.json` contains the following:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/api/**",
        "function": "app"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

If I make a direct fetch request from the React app to the API using the full absolute API url, everything works hunky dory:

```
try {
    const url = 'https://us-central1-[my-app-name]-app.cloudfunctions.net/app/api/v1.0/auth/status';
    const response = await fetch(url, 
      {
        method: 'GET',
        credentials: 'include',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      }
    );
    json = await response.json();
    console.log(json); // {"isAuthenticated":true}
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
```

The API checks for the existence of a user in session and returns a response accordingly.

However, if I attempt to access the API through the rewrites proxy I've configured in the `firebase.json` file, using just the relative url `/api/v1.0/auth/status` then I still get a response (which confirms Firebase proxies the request appropriately), but the `isAuthenticated` flag is set to false, rather than true.

I assumed that this is because the proxied request is missing my valuable 'withCredentials' header, so I set this in the `firebase.json` file too:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/api/**",
        "function": "app"
      }
    ],
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "/api/**",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials",
            "value": "true"
          },
          {
            "key": "Content-Type",
            "value": "application/json"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

However, this appears to have no effect. Is there something I'm missing?

**Edit:** On closer inspection I believe it's because the cookie header isn't being passed onto the functions app when Firebase proxies the request (the 'credentials' headers shouldn't be required as it's not cross-origin), so I believe there must be some way to tell Firebase to include cookies in the rewrite/proxied request?

Answer (score 0):

**You can include this code in your express configuration.
This would solve cors problem**

```
// allow-cors
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');
    next();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, there isn't an issue with the express server as requests made to the API directly from the React application work. The problem is when I make a fetch request from the React application to `/api/**` which Firebase proxies to the Functions `app` via the rewrites rules.